# Prove that potential is non-decreasing for any spherically symmetric system

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematical-astronomy

I am trying to prove that the potential of a spherically symmetric stellar system is non-decreasing (source of problem [2016 Paper 4 Question 7, Astrophysics Tripos](https://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/sites/default/files/Papers_1-4_2016.pdf)).

What I did is the following.

We want to show:
$$\frac{d \Phi}{dr} \geqslant 0 \quad \forall r$$
We know:
$$\nabla^{2} \Phi=4 \pi G \rho$$
Expand:
$$\frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{d}{d r}\left(r^{2} \frac{d}{d r} \Phi\right)=4 \pi G\rho$$
Multiply up by $r^2$, integrate up, divide by $r^2$, get:
$$\frac{d}{d r} \Phi=\frac{4 \pi G}{r^{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{r} \rho\left(r^{\prime}\right) r^{\prime 2} d r^{\prime}+C\right)$$
Where $C$ is free to choose. And if I choose $C$ to be a large negative number, then $\frac{d\Phi}{dr}<0$, the opposite of what I was trying to prove.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $C$ is not a free parameter and is instead determined by the boundary conditions

Comment: Oh ok. My reasoning would be: the integral term goes to zero as r goes to zero, so the gradient of the potential goes as $~r^-2$. To avoid infite gradients, $C$ must be zero. Does this sound reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $F : r\mapsto r^2 \dfrac{\mathrm{d}\Phi}{\mathrm{d}r} $ you have $F'(r) = 4\pi G \rho(r) r^2$ thus by integrating :

$$ \displaystyle \int_0^rF'(\hat{r})\mathrm{d}\hat{r}=4\pi G\int_0^r \rho(\hat{r}) \hat{r}^2 \mathrm{d}\hat{r}$$

But $$ \displaystyle \int_0^rF'(\hat{r})\mathrm{d}\hat{r} = F(r)-F(0) = r^2 \dfrac{\mathrm{d}\Phi}{\mathrm{d}r} -0 $$

Therefore :

$$  r^2 \dfrac{\mathrm{d}\Phi}{\mathrm{d}r}  = 4\pi G\int_0^r \rho(\hat{r}) \hat{r}^2 \mathrm{d}\hat{r}$$

Comment: I made the assumption that $\Phi'(0)$ is finite.